# Vim command mode complete word

Tags: vim, tab-completion

Is there a way to get Vim in command mode to complete words from the current file? Say I have this file:

```
one
two
three
once
```

and I enter command line mode

```
:myruncommand o|
```

where `|` denotes the cursor position. How do I make Vim complete `one` or `once` when pressing Tab?

Comment: [Add completion in command line for '/', '?' and ':.../'](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2731)

Comment: Quote from the script description: "In ':' mode, completion is available only after a '/'." Not really what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible natively, but it took about one minute to find [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222) and [this one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1480) on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/).

Answer (score 6):

jamesc's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/941915/219388) would often be the most convenient, but for when you know ahead of time that you'll want to use autocomplete for a command or search string, or other functions only available in a buffer, here's another way to get to the appropriate buffers:

- Type <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> to open the command buffer
- Type <kbd>a</kbd> to start entering the new command:
  `myruncommand o`
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for keyword completion, just as in jamesc's answer

Basically, <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> does the same thing as <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: let you enter commands as if you're entering text in a buffer. Similarly, <kbd>q</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> both let you type search strings in a buffer.

Comment: Great answer. Command buffer is something that I'd definitely like to be better at using.

Comment: @jamesc: I'm glad it was helpful for you. I didn't know about `Ctrl+F`, so your answer helped me, too.

Answer (score 4):

Although true that this can't be completed natively with 'tab', there is the possibility of:

- Entering the command you want in command line mode. For the example above this was:

  ```
  :myruncommand o
  ```
- Now press `Ctrl-F` to enter the command window.
- Use `A` move to the end of the line and enter Insert mode.
- Use `Ctrl-N` / `Ctrl-P` to open keyword completion and select the option you want - in this example both `one` and `once` should be available since they are in an open buffer.

I've added this answer because my search for "vim complete word in command mode" brought me here and it seems to be a workable solution, even though it doesn't use the 'tab' key.

This works for me in Vim 7.4

Comment: I should've guessed there was an easy way to go to the command/search buffer while already entering a command or search string! Thanks! I've added an answer based on yours, for the way I already knew. But doubtlessly, `Ctrl+F` is more convenient in many cases. http://superuser.com/a/1016058/219388

Answer (score 1):

Completion is available if you enter history of command mode. Very handy to alter or repeat previously used commands.

Press *q:* in normal mode to enter command history pane.

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history for more details.

Comment: In command line mode, if you type `Ctrl-f` the command line history opens, and if you want to close that window you can type `Ctrl-w q`